Instant Apps in Flutter
Hi I am trying to enable Instant Apps Feature in my already existing Flutter App but I am unable to find any comprehensive documentation to guide me through the procedure. Most of the articles I found leave a lot of to be desired in terms of comprehensiveness. How do I go about it? And more importantly is it even feasible? I keep reading that it is not possible with frameworks like Flutter or React Native

Have you read this article ?
Link: https://medium.com/inspireui/how-to-build-flutter-instant-app-with-fluxstore-7d14c4630ae6

Yes this was the article I followed. When I run my app in an emulator I can choose to run it in instant app mode. But the problem arises when I want to deploy it to play store. Play Store demands this  app already be in production for it to have instant feature. This is where I am stumped. Also the ia call the article uses to generate the link isn't working as I keep getting ia isn't recognised
